# SQL server services not getting started

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-config-manager

I am getting below two errors when I try to start SQL server from services.

[image: Error description from Event Viewer]

[image]

This issue started since I messed up something with SQL server configuration manager in order to add an alias so I can login with localhost name.

Can anyone please help me? I have already searched plenty places to resolve this.

Comment: I suggest doing what the error says then, and restore a copy of `master`, then learn from your mistakes and don't mess with things you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the advice, examine the errorlog and make the appropriate corrections so the database can run the upgrade.

Alternatively follow the later advice and restore from the backup you most recently made (before the config change right?).

Lastly if no backup and errorlog resolution fails, try to find out how your previous change affected the sql server and reverse the changes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @tyeth but i ended up by re-installing the  SQL Server.